# MySQL adding a time interval to a date represented as a bigint

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a date stored as a large integer: 20170305080000
Which represents 2017-03-05 08:00:00

MySQL can interpret that large integer as a date, in fact I can run the following statement:

```
SELECT CONVERT(20170305080000 + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE, INT)
```

which outputs

```
2017-03-05 08:15:00
```

But is it possible to ouput 20170305081500 instead?
Or how would I convert the ouput to large integer again, in the same statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value as a datetime.  First convert to a string, then to a datetime:

```
select str_to_date(CAST(20170305080000 as char), '%Y%m%d%h%i%s')
```

Now you can add the value:

```
select str_to_date(CAST(20170305080000 as char), '%Y%m%d%h%i%s') + interval 15 minute
```

And then return to a string and bigint:

```
select cast(date_format(str_to_date(CAST(20170305080000 as char), '%Y%m%d%h%i%s') + interval 15 minute, '%Y%m%d%h%i%s00') as bigint)
```

You will note that I prefer explicit casts to implicit ones.  But there is a challenge with the fractional seconds.

Interesting, I find that implicit conversion works but explicit conversion seems to generate an error:

```
select CONVERT(20170305080000 + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE, datetime) + 0
```

There is still the issue of fractional seconds, though, so you really need:

```
select CONVERT(20170305080000 + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE, datetime) * 100
```

Comment: Yes, I also kept bashing my head about that oddity. Thanks, this works